# Accept Domain Only But Drop IP address to access port 80

Tags: iptables

Our Server IP address : 192.112.1.xxx 
Domain : testing.com
I Want ACCEPT testing.com to access port 80 and DROP Server IP Address 192.112.1.xxx to access port 80 in iptables contos 6?

Answer (score 3):

The network layer is incapable of distinguishing, because when you access testing.com, it has already been resolved to the IP address in question.

For webservers, to get around this limitation, web browsers send a `Host` header that includes the domain used. Therefore, you need to:

- Set up a virtual host on your webserver that responds to testing.com
- Set up a default virtual host on your webserver that just denies everything. How this is done for Nginx, Apache, or whatever you're using, can be found elsewhere.